# "tableau-server" openidc id_token not validated (errorCode=69) by tableau-server. vizportal log says wasIssuedByOurIdP:false

Tags: keycloak, tableau-api, openid-connect

Trying to setup openid-connect login for tableau-server-2022-3-10.x86_64 users using keycloak 19.0.3,
the "id_token verification failed (errorCode=69)" at [step 6](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-gb/openid_auth.htm)

it makes no difference whether client_authentication is set to client_secret_basic or client_secret_post

upon hitting http://tableau-openidc.domain.some the user is redirected to keycloack login and can authentify using its password.

the access and id tokens are well received by tableau and logged

when [activating extended logging](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/openid_auth_troubleshooting.htm#error-69-unable-to-sign-in).

Following logs says:

`parsing response. 2023-10-30 18:03:37.499 +0000 () catalina-exec-7 vizportal: DEBUG com.tableausoftware.domain.user.openid.OpenIDConnectHelper - Validating access token received.`

`2023-10-30 18:03:37.549 +0000 () catalina-exec-7 vizportal: DEBUG com.tableausoftware.domain.user.openid.OpenIDConnectHelper - Verifying access token isSignatureValid:true, isDestinedToUs:true,` *wasIssuedByOurIdP:false*`, isTheTokenStillCurrent:true`

`2023-10-30 18:03:37.549 +0000 () catalina-exec-7 vizportal: WARN  com.tableausoftware.api.webclient.WebClientGetAuthenticationController - WebClientGetAuthenticationController failed during OpenID login attempt`

`com.tableausoftware.domain.exceptions.AuthenticationException: id_token verification failed (errorCode=69) at com.tableausoftware.domain.user.openid.OpenIDConnectHelper.authorizeUserViaAccessToken(OpenIDConnectHelper.java:433) ~[tab-domain-user-latest.jar:?]`

both access- and id-token can be decoded (for ex: using https://jwt.io/) and validated using the x5c certificate found at http://keycloack:8090/auth/realms/my/protocol/openid-connect/certs
within the id-token following claims are found:

- "sub": "d1b73ca0-cd07-415e-801e-4dc7534b8a2c"
- "email": "user-1@local.test"
- "scope": "openid profile email"

(I also tried ;-) with openid and profile claims with email as value with same result:

- "openid": "user-1@local.test"
- "profile": "user-1@local.test"
  )

keycloack is configured with:

- Credetntials/Client And Id Secret
- Settings/Client Id/some-clientid
- Settings/Name/some-clientid
- Root Url: http://tableau-openid.domain.some
- Client authentication: On
- Authentication flow: Standard Flow, Service accounts roles (or not)

tableau-server is configured with:

- tsm authentication openid configure 
  --client-id "some-clientid" 
  --client-secret "abCDEfgHiJ2kl409m261N2OPqrS0tuVx" 
  --config-url http://keycloak:8090/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration 
  --return-url "https://tableau-openid.domain.some"
- tsm authentication openid enable

Local identity store:

- tsm settings import -f /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/scripts.20223.23.1234.5678/config.json
- tsm pending-changes apply

tableau-server local users are set from a csv

- `tabcmd createusers ./users.csv --server http://tableau-openidc.domain.some --username tableau-admin`
- users.csv:

`user-1@local.test,password,email,Viewer,,,user-1@local.test`

`d1b73ca0-cd07-415e-801e-4dc7534b8a2c,password,sub,Viewer,,,user-1@local.test`

`user-1,password,name,Viewer,,,user-1@local.test`

Comment: managed to add the tableau-server in the aud claim of the access_token, but couldn't remove the previous valiue resulting in : `"aud": [
    "some-clientid",
    "account"
  ],` but I couldn't update the iss claim that seems hardcoded to http://keycloak:8090/auth/realms/myrealm  whose value is never declared explicitely in tableau's openid config.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to run `tsm configuration set -k vizportal.openid.ignore_jwk -v true`, like if keycloack was not supporting JWK validation (cf: ignore_jwk option in [doc](https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/entity_openid.htm))